# MediaCodec decode && encode on-the-fly

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I want convert some audio tracks from video files from AAC 5.1 (not only but for starting) to AAC 2 (just because ac3 not supported by MediaMuxer and vorbis and opus encoders has not hardware support in Pixel 2) and use callbacks for MediaCodec. I wrote code like that:

```java
mExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
mExtractor.setDataSource(source.getPath());
mExtractor.selectTrack(trackNumber);

MediaFormat sourceMf = mExtractor.getTrackFormat(trackNumber);
mDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(sourceMf.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME));
mDecoder.setCallback(createCallbackDecoder());
mDecoder.configure(sourceMf, null, null, 0);

MediaFormat wantedMediaFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC, 44100, 2);
mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC);
mEncoder.setCallback(createCallbackEncoder());
mEncoder.configure(wantedMediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(saveTo.getPath(), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

public void start() {
        mDecoder.start();
```

And callbacks

Decoder:

```java
@Override
public void onInputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec codec, int index) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(index);
    Log.i(TAG, "onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): " + byteBuffer);
    if (byteBuffer != null) {
        int offset = 0;
        long presentationTimeUs = 0;
        int flags;
        int size;
        if ((size = mExtractor.readSampleData(byteBuffer, offset)) > -1) {
            presentationTimeUs = mExtractor.getSampleTime();
            flags = mExtractor.getSampleFlags();
            mExtractor.advance();
        } else {
            flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM;
        }
        try {
            codec.queueInputBuffer(index, offset, size, presentationTimeUs, flags);
            Log.i(TAG, "onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION (decoder)!\nonInputBufferAvailable (decoder): ", e);
            throw e;
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "onInputBufferAvailable = null");
    }
}

@Override
public void onOutputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec codec, int index, @NonNull MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(index);
    Log.i(TAG, "onOutputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer with data (decoder): " + byteBuffer);
    if (byteBuffer != null) {
        ByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(info.size);
        Log.i(TAG, "onOutputBufferAvailable: allocated byteBuffer (decoder): " + buffer2);
        buffer2.put(byteBuffer);
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info2 = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        info2.flags = info.flags;
        info2.size = info.size;
        info2.presentationTimeUs = info.presentationTimeUs;
        info2.offset = info.offset;
        if (mQueue.add(new Pair<>(buffer2, info2))) {
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("onOutputBufferAvailable (decoder): added in queue: %s\n%s %s %s %s", buffer2,
                      info2.offset, info2.size, info2.presentationTimeUs, info2.flags));
            codec.releaseOutputBuffer(index, false);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "onOutputBufferAvailable = null");
    }
}

@Override
public void onOutputFormatChanged(@NonNull MediaCodec codec, @NonNull MediaFormat format) {
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("onOutputFormatChanged (decoder): OLD=%s NEW=%s", codec.getInputFormat(), format));
    mEncoder.start();
}
```

Encoder:

```
@Override
public void onInputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec codec, int index) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): index=" + index);
    Pair<ByteBuffer, MediaCodec.BufferInfo> mediaChunk;
    if ((mediaChunk = mQueue.poll()) != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): queue poll != null");
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(index);
        Log.i(TAG, "onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f queue (encoder): " + byteBuffer);
        if (byteBuffer != null) {
            int offset = mediaChunk.second.offset;
            int flags = mediaChunk.second.flags;
            long presentationTimeUs = mediaChunk.second.presentationTimeUs;
            int size = mediaChunk.second.size;
            byteBuffer.put(mediaChunk.first);
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): %s\n%s %s %s %s", mediaChunk.first,
                    mediaChunk.second.offset,
                    mediaChunk.second.size,
                    mediaChunk.second.presentationTimeUs,
                    mediaChunk.second.flags));
                codec.queueInputBuffer(index, offset, size, presentationTimeUs, flags);
                Log.i(TAG, "queueInputBuffer (encoder): SUCCESS");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION (encoder)!\nonInputBufferAvailable (encoder): ", e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): empty queue");
    }
}

@Override
public void onOutputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec codec, int index, @NonNull MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(index);
    Log.i(TAG, "onOutputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer from codec with data (encoder): " + byteBuffer);
    if (byteBuffer != null) {
        mMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackNumber, byteBuffer, info);
        Log.i(TAG, "onOutputBufferAvailable (encoder): muxer written");
        if (info.flags == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) {
            finish();
        } else {
            codec.releaseOutputBuffer(index, false);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "onOutputBufferAvailable (encoder): buffer = null");
    }
}

@Override
public void onOutputFormatChanged(@NonNull MediaCodec codec, @NonNull MediaFormat format) {
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("onOutputFormatChanged (encoder): OLD=%s NEW=%s", codec.getInputFormat(), format));
    mTrackNumber = mMuxer.addTrack(format);
    mMuxer.start();
}
```

But on executing I got exception:

```
I/MediaCodec: MediaCodec will operate in async mode
I/MediaCodec: MediaCodec will operate in async mode
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onOutputFormatChanged (decoder): OLD={sample-rate=44100, mime=audio/mp4a-latm, channel-count=1, bitrate=0} NEW={sample-rate=48000, pcm-encoding=2, mime=audio/raw, channel-count=6}
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer with data (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=32768]
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable: allocated byteBuffer (decoder): java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0]
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable (decoder): added in queue: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0]
    0 0 0 0
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer with data (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=32768]
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable: allocated byteBuffer (decoder): java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0]
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable (decoder): added in queue: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0]
    0 0 21333 0
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer with data (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=12288 cap=32768]
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable: allocated byteBuffer (decoder): java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=12288 cap=12288]
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable (decoder): added in queue: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=12288 lim=12288 cap=12288]
    0 12288 42666 0
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f readSampleData (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (decoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer with data (decoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=12288 cap=32768]
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable: allocated byteBuffer (decoder): java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=12288 cap=12288]
I/Codec: onOutputBufferAvailable (decoder): added in queue: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=12288 lim=12288 cap=12288]
    0 12288 64000 0
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): index=0
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): queue poll != null
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f queue (encoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4096 cap=4096]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0]
    0 0 0 0
I/Codec: queueInputBuffer (encoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): index=1
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): queue poll != null
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f queue (encoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4096 cap=4096]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0]
    0 0 21333 0
I/Codec: queueInputBuffer (encoder): SUCCESS
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): index=2
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): queue poll != null
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: byteBuffer b/f queue (encoder): java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4096 cap=4096]
I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=12288 lim=12288 cap=12288]
    0 12288 42666 0
E/Codec: EXCEPTION (encoder)!
    onInputBufferAvailable (encoder): 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_queueInputBuffer(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2450)
        at opensource.umnik.media2media.codec.SyncCodec$2.onInputBufferAvailable(SyncCodec.java:149)
        at android.media.MediaCodec$EventHandler.handleCallback(MediaCodec.java:1738)
        at android.media.MediaCodec$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaCodec.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

`at android.media.MediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2450)` ← this is encoder's buffer

What I did wrong?

UPD: code updated some times.
UPD2: more logs

Comment: Please dump all the arguments to `queueInputBuffer()` at the time the exception takes place, and add to your post.

Comment: ```

Log.i(TAG, String.format("onInputBufferAvailable: %s\n%s %s %s %s", mediaChunk.first,
                    mediaChunk.second.offset,
                    mediaChunk.second.size,
                    mediaChunk.second.presentationTimeUs,
                    mediaChunk.second.flags));
            codec.queueInputBuffer(index, offset, size, presentationTimeUs, flags);
```
And in logcat from line `2020-02-10 10:39:20.461 26534-26534/? I/Codec: onInputBufferAvailable: индекс=0` and follow. Or you ask something other?

Comment: OK, I missed something here, so let's try again: How do we know, from your question, which `onInputBufferAvailable()` is throwing? You have two, and it is not immediately obvious which one it is.

Comment: I rewrite logs and update exception info. Thank you for comments.

Comment: That's helpful, but I still cannot be 100% sure it's the encoder that's throwing. The stack trace is ambiguous due to the use of anonymous inner classes. Try `catch`-ing the exception, or put an explicit "queueInputBuffer SUCCESS! (encoder)" after the call.

Comment: You are going to have other problems b/c after you decode the AAC 5.1, you need to _remove_ some of the channel information. Right now it appears that you're feeding 5 to 10 channels worth of raw audio into an encoder that's expecting a single channel. `MediaCodec` doesn't do _that part_ of the conversion for you. That's causing a mismatch between your timestamps and the amount of audio enqueued, but I don't think that's what's causing your exception.

Comment: By the way, once we figure out why you're getting the `IllegalArgumentException`, I'm going to consider this question "answered". There is way too much going on here for a single question; you're going to have to ask follow-ups.

Comment: Could you dump `byteBuffer` prior to the `byteBuffer.put()`? I want to see how big it is, and make sure you are filling the entire thing up.

Comment: Added some more Log.i()

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the `IllegalArgumentException` is ultimately that you have specified a size of 12288 bytes for an input `ByteBuffer` that only has a capacity of 4096 bytes.

Note that, for the first two calls to `queueInputBuffer()` (encoder), you are not putting in any data; they are both 0-byte writes, therefor they are trivial, and they succeed. (Personally, I'd just skip the 0-byte writes).

The 3rd iteration is the first time you actually have some data to encode. But your `byteBuffer.put(mediaChunk.first)` isn't actually doing anything, because `mediaChunk.first` is already "played out". It has 0 bytes remaining. You need to "rewind" it before you do the `put()`:

`mediaChunk.first.position(0)`

Of course, now the problem is, you have 12288 bytes to write, but the destination can only fit 4096 bytes, so the `put()` will undoubtedly throw. You must write a smaller amount. This will avoid the `IllegalArgumentException`.

As I mentioned in a comment, your decoded audio contains 6 channels of 5.1 audio. (`1024 samples x 2 bytes per sample x 6 channels == 12288). Your encoder would like 2048 samples of audio (at 2 bytes per sample; I assume you have configured the encoder for 1 channel/2 bytes per sample). This may be a good time to decide how you'd like to do the "5.1 -> mono" audio conversion; that will help reduce the amount of decoded audio that needs to be copied into the encoder.